# Is it alright to return an unsaved resource in a GET request instead of 404?

Tags: rest

I have a /user-profile REST API endpoint that allows the user to retrieve (GET) and update (PUT) the user profile. This endpoint is used by the user profile editor in the front-end.

If the user doesn't have a profile yet, the profile editor should set a default value in some of the form fields. This defaulting logic is complex and needs to reside in the REST API.

My question is how do get the default value from the REST API?

In REST, we normally return HTTP 404 in /user-profile when there is no user profile but what if I modify /user-profile so that it returns an unsaved user profile with defaulted values? This unsaved profile is invalid though because some required fields aren't populated. Does this violate any REST best practices?

If it does, another solution that I thought of is to have two endpoints:

- /user-profile - returns the saved user profile or HTTP 404 when not found.
- /defaults/user-profile - calculates the default values of some of the user profile fields. This gets called by the UI when /user-profile returns 404.

This solution obviously is more complicated to implement but it follows the usual REST patterns.

Are there better solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is asking for peoples opinions, and this is explicitly off-topic here on Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] for information about what kind of questions can be asked here. If you want to get a discussion going you should check out the chat rooms, you can find those on the Stack Overflow all the way to the right in the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it alright to return an unsaved resource in a GET request instead of 404?

Yes.

You, the origin server, are *the* authority for your resources, and it is entirely at your discretion whether a given [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) has a current representation or not.

The notion of a user-profile being saved, or not saved, is an implementation detail hidden behind the uniform interface of the server.